# How to fire click event on V-btn?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

When I try to fire event on v-btn using @click it is not working. I also tried using @click.native. It doesn't help.

```
<v-flex align-start left style="margin-top:-30px;">
    <v-btn color="primary" icon :disabled="isDataFlag==1" @click.native="resetForm()">
      <v-icon>clear</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn color="warning" icon :disabled="isDataFlag==0" @click.native="updateForm()">
      <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn color="success" icon :disabled="isDataFlag==1" @click.native="submitForm()">
      <v-icon>save</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-flex>
```

There are methods in the other part with the same name. Still it is not working. I tried using v-btn click separately on other platform and it was working. What is the issue with my code?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you keep or remove the (). Where are the functions? Is it inside methods or somewhere else? Can you provide the JS code?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to remove the ()

Try this :

```
<v-btn color="primary" icon :disabled="isDataFlag==1" @click.native="resetForm">
  <v-icon>clear</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

and not sure you need .native